# Store a value in a database or calculate it?

Tags: java, database

In my Java web application I use a hexadecimal value of an integer which I store in a database.

There are two possible approaches:

- to store an integer, and a hexadecimal value of that integer in a database, and get the hexadecimal value when needed.
- to store an integer in a database, and count a hexadecimal value of that integer when needed.

There won't be a lot of this values in a database.

The operation on a hexadecimal value will occur quite rarely.

I want to make it in the best way possible. Which is the better approach, and why?

Comment: If you are going to retrieve values very rarely then go for the second option. If you are going to retrieve the values often then go for the first option. However, with a small number of values, it really doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Hexadecimal is a _representation_ of data, and, as such, shouldn't be stored in the database in that form. When you need to render a value as hex, that's when you should calculate it. Is there a special reason why you would want to go with option #1?

Comment: IMHO option 1 is best if `There won't be a lot of this values in a database.` holds true. In that way you can avoid the entire process of calculating hexadecimal value every time.

Comment: @Paul what is often for you?

Comment: @AbcXyz by often I mean like 100 per second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store only the int value and calculate hex string when needed.

**Why?**

- storing/retrieving value from DB is I/O operation and most likely slower than calculating hex value by a great deal
- storing both would be redundant
- storing both for all rows when it's only rarely used is waste of resources
- manually fixing a value in the db becomes very hard

Comment: Sounds sensible. Thanks.